# How to pull the data using a stored procedures in a Shiny App?

Tags: sql-server, shiny

I have built a simple Shiny app that execute a stored procedure which shows the results in a table. The stored procedure requires one input and is pulling the results from an existing table. This Shiny app works fine even when I deploy it into the Rstudio Connect. The problem is that the deployed shiny app does not show any results when I change the stored procedure in a way that has to save the results in a temp table and then selecting from that temp table. The same app and stored procedure work fine in the Rstudio IDE on a local machine. My actual stored procedure requires to save the results in different temp tables. I should note that I tried copying into a non-temp table and selecting from that too. It did not work.

I checked all the permission, and have given full access to run a stored procedure to even public users.

```
# Shiny App
shinyUI <- fluidPage(
     numericInput("UserNumber", "UserNumber:", value = "2200205"),
     titlePanel("Enter User Number"),
     tableOutput("tbl"))

shinyServer <- function(input, output,session) {
    my_data <- reactive({
      data <- pool %>% dbGetQuery(paste0("exec database.[dbo].        
      [StoredProcedure_test] @UserNumber= ", "'",input$UserNumber,"'")) 
                        })

output$tbl <- renderTable({
      my_data()
                          })
                                               }
shinyApp(ui = shinyUI, server = shinyServer)
```

Stored Procedure that does not work in Deployed Shiny app

```
Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure_test] @UserNumber int

 AS
 BEGIN

select top 10 UserName ,StoreName into #t1
from Database.dbo.Users
where UserNumber= @UserNumber

select * from #t1


 Return(0)
 END
```

The actual results should be two columns of UserName, StoreName  from the temp table #t1

Comment: `My actual stored procedure requires to save the results in different temp tables` -- Why? I don't see anything in that query that suggests the need for a temp table.

Comment: Eh... let me amend that... so it worked before, when you don't use a temp table, but then, when you switch it to use a temp table, even a simple one, like above, it stops working, right? Gotcha... I've seen things like this before. Try adding a `SET NOCOUNT(ON)` at the top of your sproc... and see if that makes a difference. What might be happeing is that when SQL Server run the insert into your temp tables, it reports back the number of rows affected, and that may be getting interpreted as the output in your app. Setting the nocount flag on will suppress those messages.

Comment: @TechGnome Thanks. I tried the Set NoCount On but it did not help. (SET NOCOUNT ON
GO). Regarding your first question. You are right, I don't need the temp table. but I tried to figure out why the stored procedures don't show the results and found this reason. In my actual stored proecure, I need to create different temp tables.

Comment: There should be no GO in there... it should be part of the sproc.... like this:
`Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcedure_test] @UserNumber int

 AS
 BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT(ON)

select top 10 UserName ,StoreName into #t1
from Database.dbo.Users
where UserNumber= @UserNumber

select * from #t1


 Return(0)
 END`

Comment: @TechGnome Thanks. It worked. Saved my life!